# How to connect a element matching a fullstring with the corresponding button in this case? Using Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a WebElement list with notes and another WebElement list with the corresponding buttons. If  a note in the list matches the variable fullstring I want to click on the corresponding button. E.g. if note 1 holds fullstring I want to click on the first button in the list. If note three holds the list I want to click on the corresponding third button in the button list. My code looks like this:

```
fullstring = "monthly"

signListNoteType = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpathSignListNoteType)))

noteButtonList = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpathNoteButtonList)))



for index, noteType in enumerate(signListNoteType, start=0):   # default start of index is zero
    index = index
    noteType = noteType.text
    print("Index:", index, noteType)
    
for index, noteButton in enumerate(noteButtonList, start=0):   # default start of index is zero
    index = index
    noteButton = noteButton
    print("Index:", index, noteButton)

if noteType == fullstring:
```

But I don't know how to code the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
for i in range(len(signListNoteType)):
    if signListNoteType[i].text == fullstring:
        noteButtonList[i].click()
```